# Multiple sub-mappers using same input type

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to build DTOs split into sub-DTOs, taking information from the same big object. To do that, I have split the mapping logic into multiple submappers (one per sub-DTO).

When the submapper uses the same input type than the parent, it is somehow ignored in the MapperImpl generation. But when the input type is different, then it works like a charm.

```
public class MainDTO {
    Integer id;
    SubDTO1 subDTO1;
    SubDTO2 subDTO2;
}

@Mapper(uses = { SubMapper1.class, SubMapper2.class })
public interface MainMapper {
    MainDTO toDto(Entity entity);
}

@Mapper
public interface SubMapper1 {
    SubDTO1 toDto(Entity entity); // KO
}

@Mapper
public interface SubMapper2 {
    SubDTO2 toDto(OtherEntity entity); // OK
}
```

Generated MapperImpl :

```
@Component
public class MainMapperImpl implements MainMapper {
    @Autowired
    private SubMapper2 submapper2;

    // No Submapper1 !

    ....
}
```

Any idea how I could fix this without putting the whole mapping logic into MainDTO?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not sure that I am following. Where is this `OtherEntity` coming from, is it part of `Entity` or is it something else?

Comment: @Filip In my case yes, `OtherEntity` is part of `Entity`. But my problem is more about understanding why I don't seem to be able to use sub-mappers using the same input type than the main mapper (`Entity`, which here is a monster object with dozens of fields I'm trying to separated in a nice domain object).

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that `OtherEntity` is `Entity`...
I added a few Mappings. And the code seems to work as you intended.

```
@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "subDTO1", source = "entity")
@Mapping(target = "subDTO2", source = "entity")
MainDTO toDto(Entity entity);
```

This compiles to MainMapperImpl.class:

```
@Autowired
private SubMapper1 subMapper1;
@Autowired
private SubMapper2 subMapper2;

public MainMapperImpl() {
}
```

Unless i misunderstood your question this should be the intended result.

Please leave a comment if I've misunderstood you.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I have been busy with other matters. I have tried your solution and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help ! :)